# Deleting images with the same filename, keeping file with largest filesize

Tags: file, automation, file-manager

I have a massive bank of images (8000 files) however they relate to only 700 products and are basically just different sizes of the same image. The images are named like:

- avao-sit_3 3.jpg
- avao-sit_3 2.jpg
- avao-sit_3 1.jpg
- avao-sit_3.jpg
- avao-bod-fast5_5_1 3.jpg
- avao-bod-fast5_5_1 2.jpg
- avao-bod-fast5_5_1 1.jpg
- avao-bod-fast5_5_1.jpg

I would like to know if it's possible to delete all files of the same name (baring in mind the file names are slightly different with 2 3 4 etc at the end) but keep the one with the largest file size.

Is this possible or will I have to manually do this?

Comment: What platform are you on? Windows? Linux? You do mean the general "file-manager" right? That's not a specific program.  On Windows you can use command prompt with "del" and wildcards; so "del avao-sit*" and on Linux you can use "rm avao-sit*" and Mac uses very similar commands to Linux since it's Unix based.  Do you want to automate this process?

Comment: Good question, ideally I'd like to do this locally on my mac, however I have access to a linux server if that's any easier.

Comment: I mean general file manager yep, i'd love to automate it all so that I don't end up spending hours doing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up manually completing this… fun ;)!